How to record robo script for release build
I've an android app in play store for 5 years now. I have published an upload to store and it was rejected due to testing failure. I learned that we need a successful robo test to publish the app hereafter. My app entry screen is Firebase phone auth which is also done by Firebase AUthUI. The authUI have a spinner for country code selection, phonenumber, and then the OTP. I've recorded the scirpt in android studio and then upload it to the Firebase testLab, still the test is not executing as the robo test can't select the country code in testlab. I've learned that the release build which have minifyEnabled may have different resource id than debug build but I can't record robo script in release build.
Funny part is the robo scirpt which I have logged in android studio is not even uploading to play console pre launch report.
How to record robo script in release build?
Below is the robo script recorded in android studio
"roboscript": {
  "executionMode": {
    "strict": false
  },
  "postscript": {
    "terminate": false
  }
}
[
  {
    "crawlStage": "crawl",
    "contextDescriptor": {
      "condition": "app_under_test_shown"
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "eventType": "PERMISSIONS_REQUEST",
        "timestamp": 1733621126670,
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "requestedPermissions": [
          "android.permission.CAMERA",
          "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
          "android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS",
          "android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
        ],
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": []
      },
      {
        "eventType": "LIST_ITEM_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1733621150103,
        "replacementText": " India +91",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": 101,
            "groupViewChildPosition": -1,
            "resourceId": "android:id/text1",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": " India +91"
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621164361,
        "replacementText": "1234567899",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/phone_number",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/phone_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1733621194086,
        "replacementText": "Verify Phone Number",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/send_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "Verify Phone Number"
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.ScrollView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621216041,
        "replacementText": "- - - - - -1",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "- - - - - -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621218974,
        "replacementText": "12 - - - - -",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "1 - - - - -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621221529,
        "replacementText": "1 23 - - - -",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "1 2 - - - -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621224272,
        "replacementText": "1 2 34 - - -",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "1 2 3 - - -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621226918,
        "replacementText": "1 2 3 45 - -",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "1 2 3 4 - -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED",
        "timestamp": 1733621229564,
        "replacementText": "1 2 3 4 56 -",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": true,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.SpacedEditText",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": "1 2 3 4 5 -"
          },
          {
            "className": "android.widget.FrameLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/confirmation_code_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1733621269360,
        "replacementText": "",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "androidx.cardview.widget.CardView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 5,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/pigeon_card",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1733621280113,
        "replacementText": "",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": 0,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": -1,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/birds_item_layout",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/birdsHomeRecycleView",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
        "timestamp": 1733621288743,
        "replacementText": "",
        "actionCode": -1,
        "delayTime": 0,
        "canScrollTo": false,
        "elementDescriptors": [
          {
            "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
            "resourceId": "",
            "contentDescription": "Navigate up",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/action_bar",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          },
          {
            "className": "androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer",
            "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
            "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
            "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
            "resourceId": "com.sstech.racemanager:id/action_bar_container",
            "contentDescription": "",
            "text": ""
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]

